# What is the name of this theorem regarding arrays?

Tags: complex-analysis

Apologize if this is inappropriate but I couldn't find any source that explains this.

> $(a_{m,n})$ with $m,n\geq 0$ be array of complex numbers. If
> $\sum\limits^{\infty}_{m=0}\sum\limits^{\infty}_{m=0}\mid
>  a_{m,n}\mid<\infty$ then the value of
> $\sum\limits^{\infty}_{n=0}\sum\limits^{\infty}_{m=0}a_{m,n}$ is
> independent of the order it is summed. In particular,
> $\sum\limits^{\infty}_{n=0}\sum\limits^{\infty}_{m=0}a_{m,n}=\sum\limits^{\infty}_{m=0}\sum\limits^{\infty}_{n=0}a_{m,n}=\sum\limits^{\infty}_{n=0}\sum\limits^{\infty}_{k=0}a_{k,n-k}$

Comment: Fubini's theorem?

Comment: I don't know a name for this, but it's basically a question about absolute convergence of double series. That's been discussed a few times on this site, e.g., https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2305138/absolute-convergence-of-double-series