What is the summation order when writing $\sum_{i,j=1}^\infty$?
Especially for a conditionally convergent series where summation order matters?
If it is equivalent to $\sum_{i=1}^\infty\sum_{j=1}^\infty$, does it mean that $\sum_{i,j=1}^\infty\ne\sum_{j,i=1}^\infty$?
Example: I saw people claiming
$$\sum_{m,n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^{m+n}\,mn}{(m+n)^2}=\frac{\ln 2}{6}-\frac{1}{24}$$
While it is probably correct in some way, if I "transform" it into
$$
\sum_{m,n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^{m+n}\,mn}{(m+n)^2}\stackrel{?}{=}\sum_{s=2}^\infty\frac{(-1)^s}{s^2}\sum_{m=1}^{s-1}m(s-m)=\sum_{s=2}^\infty\frac{(-1)^s(s+1)(s-1)}{6s},
$$
we got a divergent series. So should I take $\sum_{i,j=1}^\infty$ as $\sum_{i=1}^\infty\sum_{j=1}^\infty$ by default? Or should we not write $\sum_{i,j=1}^\infty$ for a conditionally convergent series in the first place?

Why not use a single index?

I would call this ill-defined without more details.

@UDAC do you mean $\sum_{i,j=1}^\infty$ should not be used in the first place for such a series?

@Ziyuan What series? I don’t see any series in your question. Can you provide an example?

I can only interprete this as $\sum_{(i,j)\in\mathbb N^2}$ and hence hope for absolute convergence

@UDAC an example is added.

The notation itself implies that the order of summation is irrelevant. So your example is ill-formed.

@TonyK so the conclusion is that we shouldn't use $\sum_{i,j=1}^\infty$ for a conditionally convergent series.

I suppose, if $\sum_{i=1}^\infty (\sum_{j=1}^\infty a_{ij})$ and $\sum_{j=1}^\infty (\sum_{i=1}^\infty a_{ij})$ both exist and have the same value, then the expression is unambiguous. But I wouldn't use it myself.

I agree with comments that this notation asks for trouble, but if forced to make an interpretation for a conditionally-convergent double sequence I'd assume it means, analogously to the Cauchy product of series and as in your guess (with indices shifted to start at $0$ for pleasantness),$$\sum_{i,j=0}^{\infty} = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\sum_{i=0}^{k}.$$Since that diverges for the series in question, we're back to ill-defined.

@AndrewD.Hwang: (i) You can't start the OP's sequence at $0$, because then the first term would be $0/0$. (ii) In the OP's notation, each non-diagonal term occurs twice, as $a_{ij}$ and $a_{ji}$. In your rewrite, that is not the case.

@TonyK (i) Naturally we'd have to shift the formula for the terms accordingly if using the proposed indices. The point was to avoid the relatively ugly expression $\sum\limits_{k=2}^\infty \sum\limits_{i=1}^{k-1}$. (ii) Both sums are taken over $\mathbf{N} \times \mathbf{N}$ (mod details about whether or not $0$ is a natural number)...?

@TonyK To clarify further, for my (ii) claim to be correct, we do have to re-index the terms as in a Cauchy product (i.e., sum over $a_{i, k-i}$).

For the concept of convergence of a sum $\sum_{i, j = 1}^\infty a_{ij}$ see RRL's answer to https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2305138. In the absolutely convergent case we have  $\sum_{i, j = 1}^\infty =  \sum_{i = 1}^\infty\sum_{j = 1}^\infty = \sum_{j = 1}^\infty\sum_{i = 1}^\infty$. This is certainly wrong for conditionally convergent series, but I do not have examples.

Not an answer to the convergence issue but it took me a few hours to reproduce your
transformation to which I herewith congratulate:
For finite $N\,,$
\begin{align}
&\sum_{m=1}^N\sum_{n=1}^{N-m+1}\frac{(-1)^{m+n}\,mn}{(m+n)^2}=
\sum_{m=1}^N\;\sum_{s=m+1}^{N}\frac{(-1)^s\,m(s-m)}{s^2}\\[2mm]
&=\sum_{s=2}^{N+1}\;\sum_{m=1}^{\textstyle s}\;\frac{(-1)^s\,m(s-m)}{s^2}\\[2mm]
&=\sum_{s=2}^{N+1}\;\frac{(-1)^s}{s}\frac{(s+1)s}{2}-\frac{(-1)^s}{s^2}\frac{(2s+1)(s+1)s}{6}\\[2mm]
&=\sum_{s=2}^{N+1}\;\frac{(-1)^s(s+1)}{2}-\frac{(-1)^s}{s}\frac{(2s+1)(s+1)}{6}\\[2mm]
&=\sum_{s=2}^{N+1}\frac{(-1)^s(s+1)}{2}\left\{1-\frac{2s+1}{3s}\right\}\\[2mm]
&=\sum_{s=2}^{N+1}\frac{(-1)^s(s+1)}{2}\frac{s-1}{3s}\\[2mm]
&=\sum_{s=2}^{N+1}\frac{(-1)^s(s+1)(s-1)}{6s}\\[2mm]
&=\sum_{s=2}^{N+1}\frac{(-1)^s(s^2-1)}{6s}\\[2mm]
&=\frac16\sum_{s=2}^{N+1}(-1)^s\left(s-\frac1s\right)\,.
\end{align}
I checked this numerically for a few examples of $N\,.$
In the derivation I used
$$
\sum_{m=1}^{\textstyle s}m^2=\frac{(2 s + 1) (s + 1) s}{6}
$$
(see here).
From the Mercator series we know that
$$
1-\ln 2=\sum_{s=2}^\infty \frac{(-1)^s}{s}\,.
$$
When $N$ is odd
$$
2\;\underbrace{-3+4}_{1}\;\underbrace{-5+6}_{1}\;-\dots\underbrace{-N+(N+1)}_{1}=2+\frac{N-1}{2}\to \infty\,,N\to\infty\,.
$$
So we have a diverging series.
Trying another order of summation I leave to the gentle reader.
